# How to fetch data from a session variable having an array

Tags: php, arrays, session-variables

I have a session variable storing an array in it. Now, in another PHP page, I want to print these array values row by row... Just like the result from `mysqli_fetch_array` function does

```
$sql="SELECT complaints.c_id , user.first_name , user.last_name  FROM ogc.complaints , ogc.user WHERE complaints.department='$deptname' and complaints.id=user.id and complaints.district='$distr' " or die(mysql_error());
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql) ;
$count=mysqli_num_rows($result);
if(count>0)
{
    $row = array();
    $arr_row[]=array();
    while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result ) )   
    {   
        $arr_row[]=$row;
        $_SESSION[ 'arrrows' ] = $arr_row;
        header("location:dists.php");
    }
}
```

In the dists.php

```
    session_start();
    $result=$_SESSION['arrrows'];
```

Now, I want to use this $result to access individual rows and columns of the array by the column names of different rows

Comment: Can you add some code to your question? You may have to look into serialization but I am not entirely sure.

Comment: What does the session variable with the array look like ?

Comment: I am storing the result of a query in a  session variable in one page and in another page, I want to use this session variable to print database values like the values in particluar coumns

Comment: Side note: you may want to add a `die;` after `header("location:dists.php");` line or the code, considering you have some of it after that block, will still get executed before the redirect.

Comment: No, there's no code after the header, just that 'if' loop ends.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`foreach()`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php):

```
foreach($_SESSION['array'] as $row) {
   echo $row;
}
```

Comment: @Vyshnavi Samudrala ... and move the `$_SESSION[ 'arrrows' ] = $arr_row;` line to after the `while()` block.